# Visiblox, WPF: Display labeled markers in a chart

Tags: wpf, charts, visiblox

is there a way to add some markers, like points or vertical lines with text labels to a visiblox chart?

Cheers,
Lutz

Answer (score 5):

The premium version of Visiblox supports the concept of annotations; elements which are anchored to values on your X and/or Y axes. The Visiblox API supports the following annotations out-of-the-box:

- Ellipse / circle
- Rectangle / square
- Lines (horizontal, vertical, point-to-point)
- Text labels
- Text labels anchored to datapoints (callout)

Annotations can be placed on the chart programmatically, and thereafter can be moved by the user via 'grippers'.

For a good idea of what is easily possible, see the following demo application:

http://www.visiblox.com/examples/Hindsight

Comment: hi colinE, the hindsight application includes all the features I need, but there is no source code for that example. I dont really need more than vertical lines and textmarker within the chart. are these two features only included in the premium version?

Comment: Yes, annotations are a premium feature.